# XeLaTeX, \includegraphics and \hyperlink

Tags: graphics, xetex, hyperref, links

I have question regarding XeLaTeX. I have switched from LaTeX to XeLaTeX because I wanted to use ttf fonts and now I have a problem with `\hyperlink`. It works with text, but it doesn't with images.

So for example, when I click on the text: Dit hjem, I will go to page 2. It does not work with image.

My code:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\special{papersize=297mm,210mm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{color}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan,           % color of external links
    pdfnonfullscreenpagemode=true,
    linktoc=none,
    pdfborder={ 0 0 0}
}


\begin{document}

\hyperlink{page.2}{\includegraphics[height=14.869mm, width=14.869mm]{images/tiger}} 
\hyperlink{page.2}{\textblockcolour{white}{\fontsize{3mm}{5mm} \selectfont Dit hjem}}

\null\newpage
Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It would be a good idea to tell us what actually doesn't work. Also don't send code snippet. Always make a complete example, if I complete your code and use one of my graphics it works fine.

Comment: In my code I have a menu with an image and a text. Both are inside \hyperlink so they link to another page in document, but only text works as a link. I cann`t click on image, cause somehow it doesnt work as link.

<code> <br/>
\hyperlink{page.3}{\includegraphics[height=14.869mm, width=14.869mm]{images/dig_og_din_naermeste}}  
<br/>
\hyperlink{page.3}{\textblockcolour{white}{\fontsize{3mm}{5mm} \selectfont Dig og dine n\ae rmeste}}
<code>

Comment: You should make a small *complete* example. That is one that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Use either `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` or replace the image with one available for us too e.g. with "tiger". Add the example to your question, not as comment. Also put the log-file of the compilation somewhere on the net.

Comment: I don't get any problem from your input file.

Comment: Can you click on image ?

Comment: I have no problems either. Both links works fine. Put \listfiles at the start of your document, compile and then show -as I already suggested- your log-file.

Comment: I have no problem when I compile it using Latex, but it stops working when using xelatex. And I need to use xelatex :(

My log file can be found here: http://tinyurl.com/66od5j6
Thanks for help.

Comment: My hyperref is newer than yours. Try if it works if you update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to replicate your problem. I found a solution here: http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2005-October/002480.html

From the site:

> You could possibly hack around this by wrapping your graphic
>   inclusion in a macro that outputs glyphs at two diagonally opposite
>   corners of the image; they could be small blank glyphs (e.g.,
>   \char32), so as not to show on the page, as long as they're real
>   glyphs in a font so that xdv2pdf "sees" them. I think that would
>   trick the driver into creating the proper link area.

Here's the command that does the work (again, from the site):

```
\newsavebox{\ximagebox}
\newlength{\ximageheight}
\newsavebox{\xglyphbox}
\newlength{\xglyphheight}
\newcommand{\xbox}[1]%
  {\savebox{\ximagebox}{#1}%
  \settoheight{\ximageheight}{\usebox{\ximagebox}}%
  \savebox{\xglyphbox}{\char32}%
  \settoheight{\xglyphheight}{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}%
  \raisebox{\ximageheight}[0pt][0pt]{\raisebox{-\xglyphheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}}}%
    \usebox{\ximagebox}%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}}}
```

To be used as

```
\hyperlink{page.2}{\xbox{\includegraphics[height=14cm, width=14cm]{tiger}}}
```

Complete MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,11pt]{article} 
\special{papersize=297mm,210mm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{color}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan,           % color of external links
    pdfnonfullscreenpagemode=true,
    linktoc=none,
    pdfborder={ 0 0 0}
}


\newsavebox{\ximagebox}
\newlength{\ximageheight}
\newsavebox{\xglyphbox}
\newlength{\xglyphheight}
\newcommand{\xbox}[1]%
   {\savebox{\ximagebox}{#1}%
    \settoheight{\ximageheight}{\usebox{\ximagebox}}%
    \savebox{\xglyphbox}{\char32}%
    \settoheight{\xglyphheight}{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}%
    \raisebox{\ximageheight}[0pt][0pt]{\raisebox{-\xglyphheight}[0pt][0pt]{%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}}}%
    \usebox{\ximagebox}%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\usebox{\xglyphbox}}}}

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{page.2}{\xbox{\includegraphics[height=14cm, width=14cm]{images/tiger}}}
\hyperlink{page.2}{\textblockcolour{white}{\fontsize{3mm}{5mm} \selectfont Dit hjem}}

\null\newpage
Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: XeTeX doesn't use `xdv2pdf` any more on Mac OS X. I couldn't replicate the problem.

Comment: @egreg: I'm working on Linux, TeXlive 2011. I could replicate the problem- the above fixed it

Comment: My experiment with a Linux box (Ubuntu Natty Narwhal, TeX Live 2011) shows that the original input shown by @joanna works as expected, turning the image into a link.

Comment: This \newsavebox works for me very well :) Thank you very much for help !!!!

Comment: xelatex still has this problem from 2005 right now in 2022. why are they not fixing it?