# xelatex can't make video play

Tags: beamer, xetex

I set up `pdfpc` to and `xelatex` to be able to play videos in the pdf on linux following this tutorial: http://abarry.org/the-new-complete-guide-to-embedded-videos-in-beamer-under-linux/

The only problem is `xelatex` only manages to get the sound working, while `pdflatex` can make the video work as well, and as it seems, `lualatex` as well.

**EDIT**

This problem may be related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/href-not-working-with-image-but-ok-with-text) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31819/xelatex-includegraphics-and-hyperlink) question.